# Initialize values in array of structure in C

Tags: c, function

I want to create a function to initialize values of structure like that :

```
// main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "main.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int i, taille = 2, cmpt = 0;
    Personne joueur[2];

    for(i = 0; i < taille; i++){
        initialiserJoueur(&joueur[i]);
    }

    printf("\n%s %s : %d\n", joueur[0].nom,joueur[0].prenom, joueur[0].age);

    return 0;
}

void initialiserJoueur(Personne *joueur){
    joueur->age = 0;
    joueur->nom = "";
    joueur->prenom = "";
}
```

```
// main.h
typedef struct Personne Personne;

struct Personne {
    int age;
    char nom[100];
    char prenom[100];
};

void initialiserJoueur(Personne *joueur);
```

in function  "initialiserJoueur", the fields "nom" and "prenom" won't initialize and are red underline, an idea ?

Comment: There's perhaps an error message coming along with the red underlining

Comment: Hello, yes "The expression must be a changeable value" Personne *joueur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays can't be assigned to directly.  You need to use `strcpy` to write to one:

```
joueur->nom = strcpy("");
joueur->prenom = strcpy("");
```

Or even simpler, since you're setting all fields to 0, just initialize the array that way:

```
Personne joueur[2] = { { 0 } };
```

Comment: More specifically a string literal in C is a pointer, so `char str[80] = "text";` is not valid - I hope someone can expand on this I have got to dash out right now.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, if i initialize with 0 value, the strings types will at blank ?

Comment: @B.Christophe Yes, the `char` arrays will be initialized with all bytes 0.

Comment: @Rodney That's valid because it's an initializer.  `char str[80];  str = "text";` is not valid.

Comment: @dbush Thanks for the correction - I confirmed you are right with my compiler.